# Unknown encoding: idna in Python Requests

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-requests, http-request

I'm using Python Requests. All works great but today I get this strange error:

```
[...]
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 321, in full_url
    netloc = netloc.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')
LookupError: unknown encoding: idna
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? I'm using Python 2.7.2 from brew.

Comment: Is this being run through py2exe, or is it being run standalone? Also, try running `import encodings.idna` and see if that works.

Comment: import encodings.idna, encodings.ascii

      ImportError: No module named idna

Comment: Are you sure you are running Python 2.7.2? `encodings.idna` was not included before Python 2.3.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try adding:

```
import encodings.idna
```

in various places to sift out other errors.  I ran into this same problem working on a port of python to a new platform.  We had only partial library support and `unicodedata` was missing which was causing imports of the idna module to fail.  Once we ported `unicodedata` this error went away.