# Windows Python & AWS CLI Unknown Encoding idna

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm having the exact same issue as [another unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144254/aws-cli-upload-failed-unknown-encoding-idna), but I'm willing to give whatever code/setup needed to get the question answered properly.

Like in the post I mentioned above, I am also trying to deploy files to S3 with the AWS CLI and I receive the same error:

`upload failed: ... An HTTP Client raised and unhandled exception: unknown encoding: idna`

I have the newest version of Python and the AWS CLI. I can get the Python shell to import encodings.idna, but the AWS CLI process boots its own shell to run the commands I assume. Which may mean that I need to somehow inject the import statement into the AWS CLI process. I've tried to edit the aws.cmd programs (one in /bin and one in /scripts), but nearly every change stopped the program from working properly.

I'm not sure what to post that can help determine what my issue is, so please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw that I left this question unanswered. So, here's what I did to fix the issue.

Shortly after posting this question, I tried the [AWS CLI Windows Installer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html#install-msi-on-windows) once more and it worked. I still don't know why the initial installation didn't work, but I am able to upload to S3 via CLI without Python encoding errors.